# MQ QueueConnection manager not getting disconneted

Tags: java, queue, message-queue, ibm-mq

I have a java method to read from MQ, as given below:

```
public String getMessage() throws SecurityException, IOException {
    MQMessage rcvMessage = new MQMessage();
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    gmo.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;

    gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
    int openOptions_1 = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("Accessing queue: " + qName_out_get);
    }
    MQQueue queue1;
    String msgText = null;
    try {
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
        queue1 = qMgr.accessQueue(qName_out_get, openOptions_1);

        queue1.get(rcvMessage, gmo);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[rcvMessage.getMessageLength()];
        rcvMessage.readFully(buffer);

        msgText = new String(buffer);
                        log.info("Final message is : " + msgText);



    } catch (MQException ex) {
        log.error("A WebSphere MQ Error occured : Completion Code "
                        + ex.completionCode
                        + " Reason Code "
                        + ex.reasonCode);
        for (Throwable t = ex.getCause(); t != null; t = t.getCause()) {
            log.error("... Caused by ");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("An IOException occured whilst writing to the message buffer: "
                        + e);
    }
finally {
   queue1.close();
   qMgr.disconnect();
}
    return msgText;
}
```

I have the code in place to close the queue and disconnect from queue manager in finally block
But, the connection to the queuemanager is not getting closed.
Can anyone help me here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you say connection to the queuemanager is not getting closed? Can you provide thread dump?

Comment: The Queuemanager is maintained by some other organization. They have checked at their end using `dis chstatus` command

Comment: disconnect() function of MQException class throws cached Exception which you are not handling in finally block. Not sure how your code is even compiling. My guess would be your disconnect() call is failing.

Comment: i am handling MQ exception
the code to disconnect queue manager & closing the queue are inside a try catch block, in which MQException is handled...isnt that enough or do I have to explicitly handle cachedException?

Comment: disconnect() is in your finally statement which is outside catch statement. So need to handle MQException thrown by disconnect() as it is a cached exception. Signature of method is `public void disconnect() throws MQException`.

Comment: I meant to say that I missed out in the code that I pasted here...But I am actually handling it
`finally{try {queue1.close(); qMgr.disconnect();}catch(MQException e){e.printstacktrace()}}`

Comment: If there are no exceptions and connection still persists only way to find is to analyze thread dump. See which thread is running that is not getting killed on disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

This was a minor initialization issue. 
@Aniket Thakur : Thanks a lot for your time